# php redirect both roles to same page

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, mysqli, roles

There are two roles, the administrator role and the user role. each user must be redirected to a different page, but both are redirected to the page for the adminsitrador role.

index.php contains the login form

```
 <?php

include('conexion.php');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zxx">

<head>
<title>Inicio de Sesion</title>
<!-- Meta-Tags -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="keywords" content="Core Login Form a Responsive Web Template, Bootstrap Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Android Compatible Web Template, Smartphone Compatible Web Template, Free Webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, Sony Ericsson, Motorola Web Design">
<!-- //Meta-Tags -->
<!-- Index-Page-CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<!-- //Custom-Stylesheet-Links -->
<!--fonts -->
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mukta+Mahee:200,300,400,500,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- //fonts -->
<!-- Font-Awesome-File -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" media="all">
</head>

<body>
<h1 class="title-agile text-center">Acceder al Sistema</h1>
<div class="content-w3ls">
    <div class="agileits-grid">
        <div class="content-top-agile">
            <h2>Datos de Ingreso</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="content-bottom">
            <form action="validacion.php" method="post">
                <div class="field_w3ls">
                    <div class="field-group">
                        <input name="user" id="user" type="text" value="" placeholder="User" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-group">
                        <input id="passw" type="passw" class="form-control" name="passw" value="" placeholder="Password">
                        <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="wthree-field">
                    <input id="saveForm" name="saveForm" type="submit" value="Login" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- //content bottom -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="copyright text-center">
    <p>© 2020 Management documents
    </p>
</div>
<!--//copyright-->

</body>
<!-- //Body -->

</html>
```

validation.php the users are validated and redirects to the page corresponding to the role.

```
<?php

include('conexion.php');


$user = addslashes($_POST['user']);
$passw = addslashes($_POST['passw']);

#
$query_user = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE user = '".$user."'");
    $query_role = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT role FROM login WHERE user = '".$user."' ");
if(mysqli_num_rows($query_user) < 1){
    echo "<script> alert('Error en datos...');</script>";
    echo "<script>document.location.href = 'index.php'; </script>";
}else{
    $query_passw = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE user = '".$user."' AND password = '".$passw."' ");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query_passw) < 1) {
        echo "<script> alert('Date Error...');</script>";
        echo "<script>document.location.href = 'index.php'; </script>";
    }else{

        echo "<script> alert('SucIngreso Exitoso...');</script>";
        $role = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_role);                         
                    
        if(strcmp($role,"admin") == 0){
                        header('Location: admin.php');
                        
        }
        elseif(strcmp($role,"user") == 0){
                      header('Location: user.php');
        }
    }
}


?>
```

A query is made to know which is the role that corresponds to the user who started the session and verify the role to redirect it to the corresponding page, but both users are redirected to the page of the admin role.

Comment: change ```strcmp($role,"admin")``` into ```strcmp($role["role"],"admin")``` since mysqli_fetch_assoc returns an associative array

Comment: You need to consult some tutorials. There are many bad practices being used here. Your `fetch` usage also implies you haven't seen how that returns. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php also you don't need the same query 3 times and `$consultar_user` appears to never be set.

Answer (score 1):

i'm going to give you a general way for quick debugging in php
which is the use of `var_dump()` function,and its used to show the variable type and value, use it on variables that seems to behave wrongly.

in this case
since its always redirected to the page 'admin.php',
that means this statement is always true
`strcmp($role,"admin") == 0`
so check the variable value by using `var_dump($role);` to see what value it has on every run, it may be that the value in the database is always 'admin' so you need to check it.
And use `if($role === "admin")` instead of `if(strcmp($role,"admin") == 0)` its much clearer